# YouTube API Ad Support Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube-api, ads

I am looking into the YouTube API and have read its possible with the Android SDK that it now supports ads, meaning that channel your watching will receive the relevant ad revenue from views on the video.

Is it possible to show official YouTube ads on videos with the Objective-C API for iOS? I can't find a thing regarding this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question here: [Displaying YouTube Video ads with YouTube iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26534553/2415822)

Long story short, support for ads was removed from the iOS helper class because ads were taking users directly out of the app and opening Safari while the video was buffering. There is no way to show any official ads on videos when using the `YTPlayerView` class at this time.