# YouTube ads never show while using YouTube Android Player API

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

YouTube ads never show no matter what the player style or what the video.

Actual YouTube version: 10.18.55
YouTube Android Player API: 1.2.1

I remember that I saw some ads while was developing my app. Now I can't see any ad after hundreds of tests. This is actually a problem, because my app gets constantly suspended or rejected because of "unauthorized use" of YouTube API. Google Play Support Team thinks that I disable the ads somehow. Please confirm the issue.

Comment: Have you tried with other videos as well? Take any song from VEVO on YouTube and try with that, ads should appear.

Comment: @dextor, Just tried 7 top VEVO videos - nothing

Comment: Are you using `CHROMELESS` as the `PlayerStyle`? If so, try using the default one. In addition, what device are you testing this on?

Comment: If the Android Player API is anything like the [YouTube iOS Player Helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper), then ads aren't supported.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534553/displaying-youtube-video-ads-with-youtube-iframe/30005742#30005742

Comment: @dextor, Earlier I used CHROMLESS, now I use MINIMAL as default but tested on DEFAULT as well.
I use HTC One m7, Moto Razr, Nexus 7(2) and Samsung Tab S. Google Play Support Team was not able to see ads too.

Comment: @JAL, YouTube Android Player API is a native player, not a WebView.

Comment: @ArtemSemenov we still don't know the internals of it.  YouTube could be blocking ads in the player, we don't know.

Comment: Do we have any good news. I face the same issue here. Need help, please!

Comment: when i integrate and add youtubeplayer.jar in my android app for playing v=Id youtube videos in youtube view playing fine.when video is played its showing fullscreen mode and youTube app icons on that youtube video how to disable all icons on youtube video please help me.setshowFullscreenmode(false) for remove full screen mode off what about youtube player redirection please help me

Answer (score 3):

Same thing happened to me when I was playing video with `YoutubeStandalonePlayer` API with autoPlay flag set to true. Loading a video with autoplay set to false fixed the issue.