# Unbranded, advertisement free, video streaming with youtube api

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Is it possible to use the youtube api to provide video for an app I'm hoping to develop.

1. I want to upload videos from iOS, android and the web.
2. I want to be able to control access to my videos - i.e. they're all
   private unless my app provides access.
3. I want to stream my videos to various devices (web, iOS and android).
4. I want to stream my video without youtube adding branding or
   advertising.

If all this is possible, where do I find pricing information?

Comment: This question is way too broad.  To answer you questions about mobile ads, however, check these questions for [iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26534553/2415822) and [Android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30666406/2415822) respectively.

Comment: Paraphrasing your question, you want a full-fledged video hosting platform like Youtube, but you don't want any Youtube branding. Why then have you chosen the Youtube API? Have you researched and/or considered any other options?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester - yes that's right. That's exactly what I want. I've had a quick look at BrightCove. And I've served video's from google cloud storage before. Youtube probably do more video streaming than anyone else, and imho google do good apis, and competitive prices. I figured this was a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item #1 is possible through the YouTube API for free. #2 is sort of possible; you can set uploads to be private; however, if you want your app to allow people to view the private videos, they'll have to log in with their Google Account so your app can add them to the "shared with" list. #3 is possible through the YouTube API for free. #4 is mostly not possible; you cannot remove YouTube branding, nor can you play a video through a non-YouTube player. You can remove advertising, however.

Also note that, if you have users upload their own videos, they must log in with their Google account and uploaded videos will go into their YouTube channel, not yours. You can index them, but they could always make their own changes through YouTube later. There is no way to upload videos to anywhere other than an authenticated user's own account.

If all 4 items are absolute necessities, you should instead look at an OVP like Brightcove or Kaltura.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Vimeo PRO. I think it meets all your needs, and it's really cheap compared to other OVPs. I use this platform to stream videos from Android and iOS applications, they have a complete API, there's no advertisement, and the branding is completely invisible.